# Set asp-route-content parameter from textarea value on submit

Tags: asp.net-core, razor-pages

I have a razor-pages button tag-helper calling a asp-page-handler that has an asp-route-content parameter that needs to gets it's value from a textarea control within the razor page view on button submit. How can this be accomplished?

Razor view partial code:

```
 <form method="post">
      <div class="modal-body">
           <textarea id="content" name="content" cols="90" rows="4" placeholder="Comment" required></textarea>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
           <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
           <button type="submit" asp-page="/Post" asp-page-handler="ReplyToComment"
                   asp-route-blogid="@Model.BlogID" asp-route-parentid="@Model.ID"
                   asp-route-email="@user.Email" asp-route-author="@author"
                   asp-route-content="" class="btn btn-primary">Save Reply</button>
      </div>
 </form>
```

Razor page handler :

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostReplyToComment(int blogid, 
           int parentid, string email, string author, string content)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to either bind the textarea content to a Property on your page:

```
    [BindProperty]
    public string Content { get; set; }
```

and use the `asp-for` tag-helper on the textarea:

```
<textarea asp-for="Content" cols="90" rows="4" placeholder="Comment" required></textarea>
```

Or use the `[FromForm]` attribute in the method signature:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostReplyToComment(int blogid, 
       int parentid, string email, string author, [FromForm] string content)
```

For more information see [MS Docs on Model Binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-2.2)